# Data on the middle when is one series

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I have this area chart, and this has just one data set. My question is, how can I show that data on the middle where is the label and not besides the Y axis. I used the tickPlacement: 'between' on the xaxis option but doesn't work. Any thoughts?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: if your `xaxis` type is `"datetime"` and you have only one label, it should be in the middle.

Comment: But using category? Bescause I'm filter by quarter